# Variadic template and type deduction issue

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, variadic-templates

In question 15 of the [2012 ACCU C++ Pub quiz](http://www.pvv.org/~oma/PubQuiz_ACCU_Apr2012.pdf), I am stumped by the result.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void P(T x) { std::cout << x; }

void foo(char a) {  // foo 1
    P(3);
    P(a);
}

template <typename... A>  // foo 2
void foo(int a, A... args) {
    foo(args...);
    P(a);
}

template <typename... A>
void foo(char a, A... args) { // foo 3
    P(a);
    foo(args...);
}

int main()
{
    foo('1','2',48,'4','5');
}
```

I reasoned that it would call `foo 3`, `foo 3`, `foo 2`, `foo 3`, `foo 1`, and thus give an output of `1243548`. The actual output is `12355248`, and confirmed in my debugger as following `foo 3`, `foo 3`, `foo 2`, `foo 2`, `foo 1`. I cannot work out why the fourth `foo` call is going to `foo 2` not `foo 3`.

For reference, I compiled with gcc 4.8.1 `g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -Weffc++ -Wextra -O0 /tmp/foo.cpp -o /tmp/foo` and got no warnings at all.

---

Edit: I've just tried it on Visual Studio Express 2013, and it gives `1243548`, also with no warnings.

Is this a compiler bug in GCC / VS, or one of those awkward unspecified behaviour parts of the specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like its the order of declaration. If you forward declare the relevant overload of foo above foo 2 then you will see the result you expected, i.e put this above foo 2:

```
template <typename... A>
void foo(char a, A... args);
```

The relevant portion of the standard is in 3.4.1.4:

> A name used in global scope, outside of any function, class or
>   user-declared namespace, shall be declared before its use in global
>   scope.

And in 14.6.4.1 Dependent name resolution:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are
>   considered:
>
> — Declarations that are visible at the point of definition
>   of the template.
>
> — Declarations from namespaces associated with the
>   types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context
>   (14.6.4.1) and from the definition context.

As `args` is a dependent type, name resolution only considers names visible as the point of definition of the template. `foo 3` has not been declared by this point so can't be considered in overload resolution. On that basis Visual Studio appears to be wrong in allowing the use of `foo 3`.

Answer (score 1):

`foo 2` cannot call `foo 3` because `foo 3` is not in scope of `foo 2`.

Comment: According to the standard, section 3.3, this is exactly "scope".

Comment: So it is a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, the Visual Studio compiler implements templates in a way not conforming to the standard.